# Generic way to implement if else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, refactoring

I have got  lots of if-else statements inside dropdown list selected change event  for populating another dropdownlist based on value select in current drop downlist..
Is there any generic way to reduce this much of if-else statements with any parameter type..
and this is my code for  drop down list selected change event

```
protected void ddlBr1Type_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() == ValidationFields.FO.ToString())
      {
           ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ValidationFields.FO.ToString());
           ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
      }
      else if (ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() == ValidationFields.FW.ToString())
      {
          ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ValidationFields.FW.ToString());
            ddlBr2Type.DataBind();

     }
     else if (ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() == ValidationFields.UF.ToString())
     {
          ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ValidationFields.UF.ToString());
            ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
     }
     else if (ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() == ValidationTypes.O.ToString())
     {
         ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ValidationTypes.O.ToString());
            ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
     }
     else if (ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() == ValidationTypes.W.ToString())
     {
          ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ValidationTypes.W.ToString());
            ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
     }
     else if (ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() == ValidationTypes.P.ToString())
     {
          ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ValidationTypes.P.ToString());
            ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
     }
     else if (ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() == ValidationTypes.C.ToString())
     {
            ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ValidationTypes.C.ToString());
            ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
      }

  }
```

here ValidationTypes and validationfields are an enumlists and this is code for PopulateNearbyDropdown method

```
   private List<string> populateNearByDropdown(String Item1)
    {
        var MatchedItems =  new List<string>();
        var listofitems = new List<string> { "FO", "FW", "O", "W", "UF" };
        if (listofitems.Any(str => str.Contains(Item1)))
        {
            MatchedItems = new List<string> { Item1, ValidationTypes.P.ToString(), ValidationTypes.C.ToString() };
        }
        else if (Item1 == "P")
        {
            MatchedItems = new List<string> { Item1, ValidationTypes.C.ToString() };            
        }
        else if (Item1 == "C")
        {
            MatchedItems = new List<string> { Item1, ValidationTypes.U.ToString() };
        }
        else if (Item1 == "U"  || Item1 == "FC")
        {
            MatchedItems = new List<string> { Item1 };

        }
        return MatchedItems.ToList();
    }
```

would any one pls help on this..
Many thanks In advance...

Comment: Use a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx) statement?

Comment: How about switch case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eh?

It can be clearly simplified to

```
{
  ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString());
  ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
}
```

Unless you want some checking (that the ddlBr1Type is valid).

In that case

```
{
    var valid = new HashSet<string>{ ValidationFields.FW.ToString(), ..... };
    if (valid.Contains(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue))
    {
        ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString());
        ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: waiting for 4 more minutes to tick :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're relying on string equality, I don't think you need any logic at all. This if statement:

```
if (ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString() == ValidationFields.FO.ToString())
{
     ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ValidationFields.FO.ToString());
     ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
}
```

Can collapse to:

```
ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString());
ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
```

And all of your other if statements disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this:

```
ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString());
ddlBr2Type.DataBind();

...

private List<string> populateNearByDropdown(String Item1)
{
    switch(Item1)
    {
        case "FO":
        case "FW":
        case "O":
        case "W":
        case "UF":
            return new List<string> { Item1, ValidationTypes.P.ToString(), ValidationTypes.C.ToString() };
        case "P":
            return new List<string> { Item1, ValidationTypes.C.ToString() };
        case "C":
            return new List<string> { Item1, ValidationTypes.U.ToString() };
        case "U":
        case "FC":
            return new List<string> { Item1 };
        default:
            return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not misreading your code, this should do it:

```
protected void ddlBr1Type_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString());
  ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString());
ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have use a switch. But since every time you're repeating the right par of the comparison, and assuming it won't change, I would simply rewrite the first method like this:

```
ddlBr2Type.DataSource = populateNearByDropdown(ddlBr1Type.SelectedValue.ToString());
ddlBr2Type.DataBind();
```

As for the second one, I would have thought of a swtich/case, or maybe some Reflection for this type of values (ValidationTypes.[letter].ToString(), but it's not quite constant so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would reckon Delegate
Check[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47887/C-Delegates-Anonymous-Methods-and-Lambda-Expressio)out